# Congruence equation mod $p$ involving the multiplicative order

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Say $p$ is an odd prime s.t $p$ doesn't divide $x$.  Let $x$ belong to the exponent $n$ modulo $p$.
I need to show that if $n>1$, 
then $x + x^2 + ... + x^{n-1} ≡ -1 \mod p$

I'm not sure how to go about this.  I tried applying FLT since $p$ doesn't divide $x$ but I didn't see how it could help.  Any ideas?

Comment: This claim is false as stated: $\,2+2^2\neq -1\pmod{11}\,$ for example. The claim is true if $\,n=p\,$ ...And it's not clear to me what you mean by "let n be an exponent s.t. x "belongs modulo $\,p\,$"...belongs to **what**?

Comment: @DonAntonio: For the statement to make sense, I guess that $n$ is the multiplicative order of $x$ mod $p$. waltde, right?

Comment: Yes, "$x$ belongs to the exponent $n$ modulo $p$" is another way of saying $n$ is the multiplicative order of $x$ mod $p$. Presumably this is what OP means.

Comment: @azimut, is anybody's guess.

Comment: That is true, @GerryMyerson...yet that is not what the OP wrote.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for clarifying. Never saw this formulation before.

Comment: yeah sorry that's what I meant .. changing it now

Comment: Well @waltde, then azimut's answer solves the problem at once.

Comment: @azimut, it's a bit old-fashioned. If you type, "belongs to exponent" into Google, most of the references that come up are 100 years old.

Comment: @Don, sometimes we guess what some OP means, and sometimes we get lucky.

Comment: "Belongs to the exponent" used to be common terminology.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks again. Somehow I like old-fashioned formulations.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since $n > 1$, $x\neq 1$. By geometric summation $$x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{n-1} = (1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{n-1}) - 1 = \frac{x^n - 1}{x-1} - 1.$$

Comment: what does ${x^n - 1}/{x-1} $ represent in the final conclusion like how does this relate to mod p?

Comment: I mean $\frac{x^n - 1}{x-1} = (x^n - 1)(x - 1)^{-1}$, where $(x-1)^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $x-1$. Note that $x-1$ is invertible since $x\neq 1$ and $p$ is a prime.

Comment: oh okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

If one prefers to avoid division, note that 
$$(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^{n-1})(1-x)=x-x^{n}$$
(when we multiply out, there is *a lot* of cancellation). Since the order of $x$ modulo $p$ is $n$, we find that $x^n\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and therefore $x-x^n \equiv x-1=-(1-x)\pmod{p}$. Thus
$$(x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1})(1-x)\equiv -(1-x)\pmod{p}.$$
Since $n \gt 1$, we have $1-x\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Thus we can cancel the $1-x$, and obtain
$$x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n-1}\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$